# Performing tidyverse functions in multiple data frames with unique names using a loop in R

Tags: r

In R I have several dataframes with unique names. These names are also available in a column named as names. I need to run a loop like this

for(i in 1:length(names)) {

}

in which I will select the dataframes and do following things

1. rename the first column to series
2. remove NAs from series

filter(!is.na(`series`))

3. use the following command to name the similar names unique

group_by(`series`) %>%
mutate(`series1` = if(n( ) > 1) {paste0(`series`, row_number( ))}
else {paste0(`series`)}) %>% ungroup(series)

4. then use gather command to convert columns into rows and some rows into columns
   5 and add a column in the dataframe which has repeated values of unique dataframe name with header  label.

The problem is that my try like following in a loop is not working

colnames(names[i])[1] <- "series"

Comment: names[i] is a character string.  It is not the object being named. To get that object use get(names[i]) or you might want to put all the series into a list L <- mget(names)

Comment: If you keep related data in a list, that will make it much easier to apply transformation to many elements at once. Having a bunch of different variables not in a list but in the global workspace makes things much more difficult to work with in R. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.